# I accidentally deleted the "desktop-icons@csoriano" folder. How do I get it back?

Tags: command-line, gnome

Okay, so what I was trying to do was modify the stylesheet.css file located in that folder so that I could move the icons a little further away than what I had set and like an idiot I entered this command
("rm -rf /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano")

instead of this command:

("rm -rf /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/stylesheet.css")

So what exactly do I need to do to reinstall that folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`